# How can I fix Discord Bot Keyv [Object Promise] error?

Tags: discord.js, key-value, keyv

Im kind of new to discord.js, and I'm building a bot for the Winter season. I'm building a feature called `!gift`, which will let you gift stuff to ppl virtually. ( Not with money or anything). I am using Keyv to store how many gifts each user has received so far. Here is my code -

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  if (command === 'gift') {
    let sender = message.author.username;
    let receiver = message.mentions.users.first();
    let [sender1, gift] = args;
    if (keyv.get(receiver) === undefined) {
      keyv.set(receiver, giftcount);
    }
    let prevvalue = keyv.get(receiver).then(prevvalue => {
      return;
    
    });
    
   let currentval = keyv.set(receiver, prevvalue+=1).then(currentval => {
      return;
    });
   

    }; 
    //message.channel.send(currentval);
    message.channel.send(sender + ' has gifted ' + receiver + ' ' + gift + '! They have ' +  currentval + ' gifts right now.');

  
});
```

Before I added `.then()`, when it sent the message, it said

`They have [object Promise] gifts right now.`

My friend suggested I add `.then()` to fix that, and I did, but I have no idea where to put it, and neither did he.

When I run the above code, I get the following error -

```js
ReferenceError: currentval is not defined
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: I hope my code isn't too messy, I'm not that great at organizing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[object Promise]` isn't an error; it's the string form of a pending promise. Your friend is correct, you'd need to use `Promise#then()`, and use the variable provided in that function.

Also, use template literals to improve readability.

```js
keyv.set(receiver, (prevvalue += 1)).then((currentval) => {
 // message.channel.send(currentval);
 message.channel.send(
  `${sender} has gifted ${receiver} ${gift}! They have ${currentval} gifts right now.`
 );
});
```

---

Guides to understand promises:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises
- https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html
- https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful. I just wanted to ask if there was a way to actually read the value instead of `true` / `undefined`
Also what are template literals?

Comment: [These are template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). You can only get whatever is supplied in the resolved promise, I'd check the `keyv` docs to see more about that. You could also just use `prevvalue` instead of `currentval`